# How to encode the image into string format?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, xcode4.2, encode

I am trying to encode an image by using the below code, but the encoded data is not correct.

I am writing the code here. How can I change my code and get the correct encoded data?

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myimages.image, 90);
// NSData *encrypteddata = [imageData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *encodedImage = [Base64 encode:imageData];
NSLog(@"my encoded image is 6666%@",encodedImage);
```

It prints bulk data. And whenever I pass this code into URL an blank image is displayed instead of the original image.

Comment: What do you mean by "not correct"?

Comment: "It prints a bulk data". - yes. What are you expecting it to print?

Comment: what does the NSLog is printing in console ?

Comment: whenever this code  passes to the url.blank image displayed

Comment: @MedetiNaveenKumar your question is not at all clear...

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava hi friend .first of all i load the image and then convert into encoding string format .After that my main goal is to pass that string into a specific url.In that server my image could be displayed but in that server blank image displayed instead of original image

Comment: IF you are able to pass that string to the server and then you have to convert it back to data using base64 decoding algorithm and then you can display the image.

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava how to possible to decode my data in the server side or our side.please tell me process how is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if your [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded image string is correct, and would display as an image, on the server, do the following.

Within an HTML page, add the following.

```
<html>
    <image src="Base64 data here"/>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't use extra signatures for your posts: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures